# Launch local application from Citrix session?

Tags: citrix

We're using an ERP application (SAP R/3) with a client that is deployed via Citrix. For some use cases, I'd like to execute a local program on the client (for example to acquire some still images from a locally connected USB webcam) and then process the files. I can do this as long as the SAP GUI is run on the system that the camera is connected to, but naturally this won't work inside the citrix session. I can transfer the resulting files back to the server using a network share, but I'd still need a way to tell the Citrix client on the PC to start a local application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will fit your use-case but you can redirect local client USB devices in Citrix.
Basically make the webcam accessible from the server.

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123015

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried this, but my (admittedly rather old) Logitech webcam doesn't show up as USB device. I'll have to ask the local Citrix guru whether USB redirection is disabled globally.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in mechanism for Citrix to do this, however you don't state:

What Citrix product you're using?

What version?

What version and type of the Citrix Client (Online Plugin, Reciever tc) you're running?

You may have better luck  by looking into redirecting the client device or client drives.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this post by accident and thought that my message would be of any use to you or someone ales. Recently I had a similar problem with my webcam. I couldn't redirect it to my remote session with Citrix. I googled and found an app USB for Remote Desktop. Check for it.